# Munged arrays for JSON return in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In a controller method I am doing this:

```
    destination = Destination.new(params[:destination])

    trip = Trip.find(params[:trip_id])

    destination.city_id = params[:city_id]
    destination.trip_id = params[:trip_id]

    last_destrination = Destination.find(:last, :order => 'sort', :conditions => { :trip_id => params[:trip_id] })
    destination.sort = last_destrination ? last_destrination.sort.to_i + 1 : 1

    if trip.user_id == current_user.id and destination.save
        city = City.find(params[:city_id])

        render :json => [ 'destination' => destination, 'city' => city ]
    else
        render :status => 500
    end
```

Now I want to send the destination I just make along with the city associated with it. How the heck can I do that, as right now I get the following :

```
[
      {
            city: {
                  city: {
                      # name: "Fort Frances"
                      # latitude: 48.617
                      # created_at: "2010-12-23T16:04:00Z"
                      # updated_at: "2010-12-23T16:04:00Z"
                      # country_id: 43
                      # timezone: "-05:00"
                      # id: 951
                      # region_id: 34
                      # longitude: -93.417
                  }
            },
            destination: {
                  destination: {
                      # trip_id: 10
                      # created_at: "2010-12-23T21:24:27Z"
                      # updated_at: "2010-12-23T21:24:27Z"
                      # id: 29
                      # sort: 18
                      # city_id: 951
                  }
            }
      }
]
```

That all works fine except for the doubling up of array key names. destination.destination is no good. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
render :json => [ destination, city ]
```

--edit

This should render a single object with destination and city keys:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.include_root_in_json = false
render :json => { :destination => destination, :city => city }
```

That setting would probably be better in a separate initializer if its used throughout the application.

Comment: That gives me http://scrp.at/bN so it would be data[0].destination and date[1].city.

Comment: Thats right.. so I guess you want an object with city and destination keys?